# Chef: notify based on `execute` result failure

Tags: chef-infra

I don't want to run `bundle install` every time chef client runs on my app host I have a `bundle check` execute resource which notifies the `bundle install` resource if bundle check fails

```
execute "bundle_check" do 
  cwd node[:app][:install_dir]
  user "foo"
  command 'bundle check'
  action :run
  returns [1]
  notifies :run, "execute[bundle_install]", :immediately
  ignore_failure true
end
```

I have the `ignore_failure true` attribute set, but I'm wondering if there's a way of configuring the `notifies` attribute to notify based on return value. Essentially I don't want either return value of `bundle check` to be considered a failure, and I only want to notify if that value is 1.

Answer (score 3):

You are thinking about notifications incorrectly. What you really want in this case is a [Resource Guard](https://docs.chef.io/resources.html#guards) on the **install** resource:

```rb
command 'bundle install' do
  # ... existing parameters
  not_if 'bundle check'
end
```

This will execute the shell guard and then only run the `bundle install` command if `bundle check` fails (returns non-zero).

Comment: The documentation for `execute` explicitly warns against this.
http://docs.opscode.com/resource_execute.html
<br/>
"When using the not_if and only_if guards with the execute resource, the current working directory attribute (cwd) is not inherited from the resource."

Comment: That's a warning about PWD (which you didn't mention). Then you need to `cd /path/to/gemfile && bundle check`

Comment: You really need to do cwd, otherwise a wrong ruby may be selected if you use rbenv or rvm, so bundler gem will be not available and shell command will always report false. Also you need to cwd because Gemfile is located there, so one more source of error.

Answer (score 1):

Guard against `execute[bundle install]` with a `not_if`:

```rb
# install gem dependencies
execute 'bundle install' do
  command "bundle install --deployment --without development test"
  cwd node[:app][:install_dir]
  not_if 'bundle check', :cwd => node[:app][:install_dir]
  # ...
end
```

Note the `, :cwd => node[:app][:install_dir]`, *very important*